# How to accelerate and decelerate a gamobject according to keys pressed in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sphere as my gameobject .The sphere have to start slowly and attain a good speed and reach a constant value.In the below code I tried the acceleration reaches 50 within seconds.According to key pressed(WASD) how to increase the acceleration for player movement and decrease when I release the keys.

```
    float acceleration=0;
    public float maxspeed = 50f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);

    rb.AddForce(move * acceleration * Time.deltaTime);

    Debug.Log("accelerate " +acceleration);

    if (acceleration < maxspeed)
    {
        acceleration += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? (There's nothing to change `acceleration`, for one, but...)

Comment: @AKX when I press key the speed should increase but i dont find it increasing

Comment: Well, `acceleration` is always 0, since there's nothing to change it, so `move * acceleration * Time.deltaTime` is something like `Vector3 * 0 * 0.01`, which is `Vector3.zero`

Comment: But it will get increased in the if loop.The acceleration value reaches to 50 by fixed update.According to key pressed how to increase.

Comment: You can get the state of a key using the `Keyboard.GetKeyStates` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.getkeystates(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Comment: The `RigidBody` must not be set to be kinematic for `AddForce()` to do anything. Using Physics Materials on your colliders is also a good idea. We don't have much to go on here.

Comment: Ah, yeeah, my bad with the acceleration being zero, didn't read closely enough.

Comment: @zyonneo Its not called an *`if loop`*, it's an *if statement.* Loops...well, they loop.

Comment: What kind of control do you want with WASD? Like W accelerates forward, S-> brakes (or maybe accelerates backward), A/D steers sideways? Or, according with your presented code, W/D accelerates x/z and S/D accelerates -x/-z? Also, the max speed is comopnent wise or in magnitude?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues With present code is it possible to W accelerates forward, S- brakes (or maybe accelerates backward), A/D steers sideways with acceleration?